# Google Map not showing only google sign showing in android studio

Tags: android

I made an Activity of GoogleMap type and then as you know that all the codes automatically generated and given to us so and i created an API key and pasted it at required location then i run my app once in emulator and once in my real phone but in the both cases the google map is not showing only the google sign showing.

[Google Map not showing only google sign showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvyC2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the google map api enabled to your google key.

Comment: Didn't understand well what to do, can you explain briefly please.

Comment: Open google api console , select the api key , open google maps api and make it enabled.

Comment: i can't see any option for like selecting an api i can just copy it in my credentials so from where to go to google maps api and make it enable?